# angularjs directive is not called

Tags: angularjs, animate.css

I am trying to apply animation class on scope value change but directive just never gets called here.

```
    <md-card animateOnChange="currentCard.fab_id">
    <md-card-header-text>
      <span class="md-subhead">Id: {{currentCard.fab_id}} </span>
    </md-card-header-text>
  </md-card-header>
</md-card>
```

Directive:

```
.directive('animateOnChange', function($timeout) {
   return function(scope, element, attr) {
        scope.$watch(attr.animateOnChange, function(nv,ov) {
            if (nv!=ov) {
                element.addClass('animated shake changed');
                $timeout(function() {
                    element.removeClass('animated shake changed');
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    }
  })
```

Comment: Did you try adding `<md-card animate-on-change="currentCard.fab_id">` instead of `<md-card animateOnChange="currentCard.fab_id">`

Comment: Add an alert statement at the right beginning of the function and tell us what you see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<md-card animate-on-change="currentCard.fab_id">
```

and:

```
scope.$watch(attr.animateOnChange, function(nv,ov) {...}
```

because angularjs normalizes directive and attributes. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Thank you. I just ignored that :) One more thing though, the animate shake class from animate.css is not getting applied but css class does. Any idea?

Comment: You are adding and removing 3 classes? Or just one and there is a typo?